# Incorrect column alignment when printing table in Python using tab characters

Tags: python

I want to print a table with some labels on the top. When the labels have a short length, everything is fine; but when the labels are long, the columns do not match up!

I am using tab characters to make space. Here is the code:

```
table = """
\tX Coordinate\tY Coordinate\tResult
\t00\t00\t00
\t00\t00\t00
\t00\t00\t00
"""
print(table)
```

Output:

```
X Coordinate    Y Coordinate    Result
00      00      00
00      00      00
00      00      00
```

As you can see, `Y Coordinate` has been pushed out by `X Coordinate`! How do I make it match up!

Comment: `print` does not check the number of characters in the string and thus will not align them.

Comment: Tabs align on predefined tab stops (usually, 1 plus every 8th character).  If the text written is longer and goes over the next tab stop(s), a following tab will align to the next tab stop forward, without regard to how far into the line the cursor already is.  Tabs have always behaved this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to rely on some package that has been designed for this purpose, like **tabulate**: [Read more about it!](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

Keep in mind that you have to install this using e.g. `pip install tabulate`

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print tabulate([[00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00]], headers=['X Coordinate','Y Coordinate','Result'], tablefmt='orgtbl')
```

Or use your original table with this code:

```
alignment = len(max(table.split("\t")))+1
    
for line in table.strip().split("\n"):
    row ="{{:>{}}}".format(alignment) * len(line.strip().split("\t"))
    print row.format(*line.strip().split("\t"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use \t for alignment except the strings have the same length.

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan 03 2018, 13:52:55) [GCC]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: table = """
   ...: \tX Coordinate\tY Coordinate\tResult
   ...: \t00\t00\t00
   ...: \t00\t00\t00
   ...: \t00\t00\t00
   ...: """

In [9]: def reformat(s):
   ...:     ss = s.strip().split('\n')
   ...:     tb = [i.strip().split('\t') for i in ss]
   ...:     length = max(max(len(w) for w in words) for words in tb) + 4
   ...:     return '\n'.join(''.join(f'{w:{length}}' for w in words) for words in tb)
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [10]: print(reformat(table))
X Coordinate    Y Coordinate    Result          
00              00              00              
00              00              00              
00              00              00
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is a great resource](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) for Python string formatting in general. Using the `.format` approach, you could use padding to align all of your strings with:

```
header = ['X Coordinate', 'Y Coordinate', 'Result']
row = ['00', '00', '00']
rows = [header, row, row, row]
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:16}'.format(x) for x in r]) for r in rows]))
#X Coordinate    Y Coordinate    Result          
#00              00              00              
#00              00              00              
#00              00              00
```

Or, using f-strings:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([f'{x:16}' for x in r]) for r in rows]))
```

You can also right-align with (note the `':>16'` in the format string):

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([f'{x:>16}' for x in r]) for r in rows]))
#    X Coordinate    Y Coordinate          Result
#              00              00              00
#              00              00              00
#              00              00              00
```

So basically, put your data in to a list of lists and then decide on a desired row width and you can use the above single line to print things out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using tabulate.

First you have to import it. Do a search online how to.
If you're using Spyder like I am then in the command window for Anaconda, just type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tabulate
```

This is very useful!

```
table = [["X Coordinate", "Y Coordinate", "Result"], [00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00]]
print(tabulate(table))
```

This will yield this result:

```
------------  ------------  ------
X Coordinate  Y Coordinate  Result
0             0             0
0             0             0
0             0             0
------------  ------------  ------
```

Or you can do this:

```
table = [[00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00], [00, 00, 00]]
print(tabulate(table, headers=["X Coordinate", "Y Coordinate", "Result"]))
```

Which will yield this result:

```
  X Coordinate    Y Coordinate    Result
--------------  --------------  --------
             0               0         0
             0               0         0
             0               0         0
```

If you do not like the dashes, you can use this instead:

```
print(tabulate(table, tablefmt="plain"))
```

And this will then yield:

```
X Coordinate  Y Coordinate  Result
0             0             0
0             0             0
0             0             0
```